# Calculate the mean based on the previous consecutive trials

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the mean of every `SACCADIC_RT` for which `COMMISSION_ERROR =1`, that follows every 5 consecutive `HITS=1`, per `ID` per condition.

```
ID  | TRIAL | TRIAL_TYPE| CONDITION | COMMISSION_ERROR  | HITS| SACCADIC_RT
1     183     nogo        square_1     1                  -1    175
1     54      go          square_1    -1                   1    259
1     26      nogo        square_1     1                  -1    365
1     3       nogo        square_1     1                  -1    346
1     100     nogo        square_1     1                  -1    287
1     11      go          square_1    -1                   1    164
1     52      go          square_1    -1                   1    244
1     8       go          square_1    -1                   1    223 
1     10      go          square_1    -1                   1    183
1     21      go          square_1    -1                   1    234
1     32      go          square_1     1                  -1    221
1     2       go          square_1    -1                   1    183
1    13       nogo        square_1     0                  -1    -1
1    87       nogo        square_2     1                  -1    228
1    95       nogo        square_2     1                  -1    274
1    111      go          square_2    -1                   1    305
1    28       nogo        square_2     0                  -1    309
1    65       go          square_2    -1                   0    -1
1    40       nogo        square_1     0                  -1    199
1    19       nogo        square_1     0                  -1    207
1    28       go          square_1    -1                   1    257
2    45       nogo        square_1     1                  -1    169
2    197      nogo        square_1     1                  -1    350
2    115      nogo        square_1     1                  -1    321
2    65       go          square_2    -1                   1    298
2    24       go          square_2    -1                   0    -1
2    1        nogo        square_2     1                  -1    183
2    77       go          square_2    -1                   1    225
2    90       go          square_2    -1                   1    305
2    89       go          square_2    -1                   1    210
2    104      go          square_2    -1                   1    199
2    116      go          square_2    -1                   1    175
2    29       nogo        square_2     1                  -1    99
2    41       go          square_2    -1                   1    104
```

The sample table can be recreated in r as:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                              2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X..TRIAL.. = c(183L, 54L, 26L, 
                                                                              3L, 100L, 11L, 52L, 8L, 10L, 21L, 32L, 2L, 13L, 87L, 95L, 111L, 
                                                                              28L, 65L, 40L, 19L, 28L, 45L, 197L, 115L, 65L, 24L, 1L, 77L, 
                                                                              90L, 89L, 104L, 116L, 29L, 41L), TRIAL_TYPE. = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                         1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                         1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                         1L), .Label = c("go", "nogo"), class = "factor"), CONDITION = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2L), .Label = c("square_1", "square_2"), class = "factor"), X..COMMISSION_ERROR = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L), X..HITS. = c(-1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1L), SACCADIC_RT = c(175L, 259L, 365L, 346L, 287L, 164L, 244L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  223L, 183L, 234L, 221L, 183L, -1L, 228L, 274L, 305L, 309L, -1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  199L, 207L, 257L, 169L, 350L, 321L, 298L, -1L, 183L, 225L, 305L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  210L, 199L, 175L, 99L, 104L)), .Names = c("ID", "X..TRIAL..", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "TRIAL_TYPE.", "CONDITION", "X..COMMISSION_ERROR", "X..HITS.", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "SACCADIC_RT"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -34L))
```

So the result from this example will be like:

```
ID | CONDITION |  x
1    square_1    221
2    square_2    99
```

Comment: Where is your attempt so far?

Comment: So far, I have only tried the second bit of the question which is to calculate the mean of the SACCADIC_RT for which trials COMMISSION_ERROR =1 per ID per CONDITION with the code:    CE_mean <- with(data_file[data_file$COMISSION_ERROR == 1, ],
                aggregate(SACCADIC_RT, by = list(ID = ID, CONDITION = CONDITION), mean))
CE_mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package data.table to perform this task.

The steps are then as follows:

1) for each ID and condition calculate the rolling sum of hits

2) take only rows which satisfy 2 conditions: commision_error = 1 on previous row, there is number 5 in rolling sum column

3) calculate mean for each ID and condition in the table created in step 2

```
# load your data
data <- read.csv("./yourData.csv")

# load data table library
library(data.table)

# convert your data to data.table object
data <- data.table(data)

# group data by ID and Condition, calculate rolling sum over 5 rows
data[, roll := Reduce('+', shift(HITS, 0:4)), by = list(ID, CONDITION)]

# take only rows where there were 5 hits in a row and commission error is 1
newData <- data[shift(roll, 1) == 5 & COMMISSION_ERROR == 1]

# calculate mean of SACCADIC_RT for each ID and Condition in the new dataset
newData[, meanSacc := mean(SACCADIC_RT), by = list(ID, CONDITION)]
```

### Code Explained:

`roll := Reduce('+', shift(HITS, 0:4))`

The shift function allows you to calculate value in current row based on the value in some previous row. Here the 'Reduce('+', shift(HITS, 0:4)) 'take value of hits on a given row and add to that the value of hits on 3 previous rows. This value is then written to the new column called roll.

`newData <- data[shift(roll, 1) == 5 & COMMISSION_ERROR == 1]`

The above code keeps only rows from the original dataset, where there is value 5 in the previous row of the column `roll` and the value of `COMISSION_ERROR` on the current line is equal to 1.

`newData[, meanSacc := mean(SACCADIC_RT), by = list(ID, CONDITION)]`

The above snip calculate mean of `SACCADIC`_RT for each `ID` and `CONDITION` and the mean is calculated only from rows in the new dataset created above. The means are then written to a new value called `meanSacc`

Comment: Thanks for that @ira, however, the COMMISSION_ERROR ==1 needs to be met for the next row that follows the 5 consecutive HITS (HIT==1). The result here gives 0 observations.

Comment: @Ath It works in my case. have you tried calling newData after the last row? I just update the values in the dataset there without printing the result.

Comment: Hi, I did this yes, but when I apply with bigger dataset it doesn't seem to work. I understand taht the HITS column includes the rolling sum o 5 consecutive rows  but i am not sure what the ''roll'' column includes. Can you please explain the functions used in the code as i am not very familiar with them (e.g. Reduce and shift)

Comment: @Ath can you please tell me which row fail in your case? Also, please check the `Code Explained` part of my editted answer.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to calculate the mean `(SACCADIC_RT)` of the 5 consecutive  HITS that precede one commission error `(COMMISSION_ERROR == 1)`. However, the `newData` of the code above include only `COMMISSION_ERROR == 1`. Any ideas how to extract the preceding consecutive HITS? thanks! @ira